# Whenever CronJob Issue - Unable to execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, cron, whenever

In my Refinery Project, I am using cron job to update my one of the textfield.

**Sample code :** Code present in Model

```
def update_time
  @time = Page.all
  @time.each do |time|
    time.present_time = Time.now
    time.save
  end
end
```

Code : /config/schedule.rb

```
set :environment, 'development'

every 1.minutes do
  runner "Page.update_time"
end
```

Then run these command on the terminal :

```
$ whenever --update-crontab PageTest
[write] crontab file updated
$ crontab -l
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: .../config/schedule.rb
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/trainee2/PageDevp && 
script/rails runner -e development '\''Page.update_time'\'''

$ sudo service cron restart
```

Then, rake job is not working. I am not able to make it running. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does `Page.update_time` work from the console? The method declaration should be `def self.update_time` unless you're using the `class << self` syntax... maybe that's the problem

Comment: Yes, it works from the console.